# How can I get both header and web page content in a single call?

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I know how to use openURI to get the headers from a URL …

```
open(url){|f| pp f.meta  }
```

and I know how to get the contents of the URL

```
open(url).read
```

So how can I get both headers and contents in one call, preferably storing headers into one variable and contents into another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to reuse the result of the `open` call:

```
f = open(url)
pp f.meta
pp f.read
```